# Microsoft Sync Framework with Sync Services for ADO.NET - how does it scale?

Tags: sql-server

We are about to embark on a major project which requires an Occasionally Connected Application.

The MS Sync Framework seems to offer a good solution with Sync Services for ADO.NET.

Has anyone used this in a production app, ideally with tens of thousands of users, and can you comment on how well it scales? Any other pitfalls or gotcha's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use in quite big application, for now a lot of troubles to get it working. especially with a quite simple thing as a Row Filtering.

I saw other comments people saying it's not so fast. but I still want to try it.